# How to avoid index scans in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

I have a table named `Cell` which has columns like `Cell_ID`, `CellValue` and `CellRow`.

`Cellrow` can have values maximum 1 to 5. There is a clustered index on `Cell_`ID field. This table contains 100000 rows.

In my query I have to use the `CellRow` column in the WHERE clause like `CellRow > 3` to get data from `CellValue` field. The problem is when I do it like this then it is always table scan that makes my query very slow.

I have also checked it by putting non-clustered index on `CellRow` field but still index scan because the `CellRow` field don't have so much values, it has only 1 to 5 values each time. I can't use `CellID` in the where clause.

I am using many tables in my query like

`Table_1` is joining with `table_2` by using clustered index column and `table 2` is joining with `table_3` by using non-clustered index column and `table_3` is joining with `Cell` table by using non-clustered index.

The ending story is, I am getting different values from all the tables including cell table but when I use `CellRow` field in the WHERE clause, I am getting index scan.

Any solution :)

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post your `CREATE TABLE` batches for these tables.  Your description is very hard to follow.

Comment: No, not really - as you said yourself - `CellRow` is just not very selective - 5 possible values, 100'000 rows = roughly 20'000 rows for each value. SQL Server's query optimizer probably recognizes this and figures it's easier and more efficient to do a index scan. The only way to avoid this would be to use a more selective index, i.e. some other column that selects 2% or max. 5% of the rows for each query

Comment: @marc_s +1, that should be the answer.  SQL Server uses a certain parameter to determine when a seek is more costly than a scan (and there is a line there).  You have the right answer.

Comment: You could also consider making a covering NCI or changing the clustered index to be on `CellRow, Cell_ID` to benefit this type of range query (and adding a new unique NCI for `Cell_ID`)

Comment: why not add an index on CellRow if you want to filter by that.

Comment: What about sharding the data across multiple tables? I guess it will still be a table scan, but it will only scan applicable rows. Though if your current solution is a ranged table scan, which it may be, it won't gain you much.

Comment: @marc_s: I know the selectivity is very low thats why Optimizer is doing index scan. This is the only way to get values from cell table by using cellrow in where clause.

Comment: @user999896: as long as that selectivity is a poor 20% - no, there's no "magic" to make the index scans go away. Check your execution plan - does it get the values from the index, or does it need "Key Lookup" steps to go get the data?? You didn't mention what **data types** your columns are - if the `CellValue` isn't too big, you could add it to the index (or at least *include* it in the index) to avoid costly key lookups - you'd still have the index scan, though

Comment: @marc_s: there is no key lookup. data type of cellrow is integer and cellvalue is nvarchar.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Will it work if I use mulicolumn index on cellrow and one more field in cell table that I am using for joing cell table with other tables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Any solution :)*

No, not really.

As you said yourself - `CellRow` is just not very selective - 5 possible values, 100'000 rows = roughly 20'000 rows for each possible value.

SQL Server's query optimizer recognizes this and probably figures it's easier and more efficient to do a index scan rather than a seek for 20'000 rows.

The only way to avoid this would be to use a more selective index, i.e. some other column that selects 2%, 3% or max. 5% of the rows for each query.

PS: Check your execution plan - does it get the values straight from the index, or does it need a "Key Lookup" step to go get the data??

You didn't mention what data types your columns are - if the `CellValue` isn't too big, you could add it to the index (or at least include it in the index) to avoid costly key lookups:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_CellRow_CellValues
ON dbo.Cell(CellRow) INCLUDE(CellValue)
```

You'd still have the index scan, though

Answer (score 0):

create an index on cellrow, but the optimizer might decide not to use it if it only has 5 values, but if you know that values above 3 are rare, you could add a hint to the query to sort of make the engine use that index.
EDIT: Another more complex solution that may or may not work for you is to separate cellrows in different tables, and create a view that's the union of tables for cellrows 4 and 5, that way when you query on that view, it won't use an index, but it will only traverse the involved records. This is sort of what data dictionaries do, but be careful with this, as it involves more maintenance (say, the data changes from 3 to 4, that's not a single update anymore, but a delete from table '3' and insert in table '4', for example).  Ultimately it depends on your needs. Usually this sort of things is done when you're talking of millions of records, but you can try and see if it does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `WHERE CellRow in (4, 5)` to work better than `WHERE CellRow > 3`. ----

Comment: welcome to dba.se and thanks for your answer. Would you be willing to explain in a bit more detail your reasons for expecting that?